# jenkins pipeline and git keeps on building

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I had a perfectly fine pipeline up and running until two days ago. It is configured to take the Jenkinsfile from Git from */master.
Without making any changes to the job config or upgrading any of the plugins the job started to build continuously.

So far I have tried the following:

1. Change branch from */master to refs/heads/master
2. Create a new job, identical to the original job
3. The Jenkinsfile was changed from declarative to scripted style, I reverted this and it still triggers
4. I have upgraded to the latest Jenkins (2.73.2) and upgraded all the plugins
5. Create a freestyle job for the same project, this does not trigger
6. Removed the shared library that was used, still triggers

Please let me know if you have any tips

This is the polling log of the freestle project
    Git Polling Log

```
Started on Oct 15, 2017 9:20:00 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 8a68578bf81dba01bd00e2c83981cde69933ece9 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: 8a68578bf81dba01bd00e2c83981cde69933ece9 - already built by 2
Done. Took 63 ms
No changes
```

This is the polling log of the job that keeps on triggering:

```
Started on Oct 15, 2017 9:19:00 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 (origin/test-build-issue)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test-build-issue is: 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 - already built by 11
RTC : checking for changes...
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 (origin/test-build-issue)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test-build-issue is: 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 - already built by 11
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 (origin/test-build-issue)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test-build-issue is: 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 - already built by 11
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 (origin/test-build-issue)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test-build-issue is: 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 - already built by 11
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 (origin/test-build-issue)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test-build-issue is: 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 - already built by 11
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 (origin/test-build-issue)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project # timeout=10
Found 11 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/DEPT/project
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test-build-issue is: 4d210e24c65cefe2104c1629ca6954d5eb863b04 - already built by 11
Done. Took 0.66 sec
Changes found
```

Comment: what is the trigger reason in the build log ?

Comment: There is no change reported in the build log

Comment: The first line of the console log ? Build trigger by scm ? Or something else ?

Comment: Yes, the build is triggered by an SCM change. Then when you follow the link it show the above polling log. But the section under "Changes" is not present.

Comment: For now it looks solved as I moved the shared library from the legacy SCM RTC to Git. After this it looks ok at the moment. My guess is that there is an issue with shared libraries in RTC as I use RTC for other projects and don't have issues there.

Comment: Can you upload the jenkinsfile , and the start of the console log ?

Comment: Good for you !!!